# What causes the property does not exist on type ObjectConstructor error in this Vue 3 app?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3

I have been working on an SPA with **Vue 3**, **TypeScript** and **The Movie Database (TMDB) API**.

With the help of the computed property `movieQuality`, I want to style (color) the movie score "bubble" differently.

For this purpose, in `src\components\MovieDetails.vue`, I have:

```
<template>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-3">
      <div class="poster-container text-center text-sm-start my-3">
        <img
          :src="`https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w600_and_h900_bestv2/${movie.poster_path}`"
          :alt="movie.title"
          class="img-fluid shadow-sm"
        />
      </div>

      <div class="user-score">
        <strong>User Score:</strong>
        <span class="score" :class="{ good: isGood, average: isAverage , bad: isBad }">{{
          Number(movie.vote_average).toFixed(2)
        }}</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent } from "vue";
import { useRoute } from "vue-router";
import axios from "axios";
import env from "../env";
import TrailerCarousel from "./TrailerCarousel.vue";
import ActorCard from "./ActorCard.vue";

export default defineComponent({
  name: "MovieDetails",

  components: {
    TrailerCarousel,
    ActorCard,
  },

  data() {
    return {
      route: useRoute(),
      movie: Object,
      movieTrailers: [],
      movieCast: [],
    };
  },

  mounted() {
    this.getMovieDetails();
  },

  methods: {
    getMovieDetails() {
      axios
        .get(
          `${env.api_url}/movie/${this.route.params.id}?api_key=${env.api_key}`
        )
        .then((response) => {
          this.movie = response.data;
        })
        .catch((err) => console.log(err));
    },

    // More code, not relevant to the question

    // More code, not relevant to the question

  computed: {
    movieQuality() {
      switch(true) {
        case Number(this.movie.vote_average) <= 6:
          return 'bad'
          break;
        case Number(this.movie.vote_average) > 6 && Number(this.movie.vote_average) < 7.5:
          return 'average'
          break;
        default:
          return 'good'
      }
    }
  }
});
</script>

<style scoped lang="scss">

.user-score {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;

  .score {
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    margin-left: 5px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    font-size: 11px;
    line-height: 1;
    font-weight: 500;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;

    &.good {
      background: #0b8a52;
      color: #fff;
    }

    &.average {
      background: #f7ff1d;
      color: #222;
    }

    &.bad {
      background: #ff1d30;
      color: #fff;
    }
  }
}
</style>
```

#### Update

I have created a "model" in `src\models\Movie.ts`:

```
export class Movie {
    id?: number;
    adult?: boolean;
    backdrop_path?: string;
    poster_path?: string;
    title?: string;
    tagline?: string;
    overview?: string;
    genres?: any;
    original_title?: string;
    release_date?: string;
    runtime?: number;
    vote_average?: string;
}
```

I import it in the component:

```
import { Movie } from "../models/Movie";
```

and use it like so:

```
data() {
    return {
      route: useRoute(),
      movie: Movie, // I use the model now
      movieTrailers: [],
      movieCast: [],
    };
},
```

#### Stackblitz

You can see a Stackblitz **[HERE](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-typescript-vue-cli-starter-7y9c7v?file=src%2Fcomponents%2FMovieDetails.vue)**.

#### The problem

Evan thought the `vote_average` property is present in the `movie` object, the `movieQuality()` function throws the error:

> Property 'vote_average' does not exist on type 'ObjectConstructor'.

#### Questions

1. What am I doing wrong?
2. What is the most reliable way to fix this issue?

Comment: I think your data property `movie` should redeclare with some initial value that already has  vote_average property instead of simple Object

Comment: ` movie: Object` is a mistake. It's JS code, not TS type

Comment: @EstusFlask I have made a `Movie` class and now I get the error: ` Property 'vote_average' does not exist on type 'typeof Movie'`. There are no errors for other types.

Comment: It's unknown how you use it. Consider updating the question

Comment: This results in `this.movie === Movie`, `typeof this.movie === 'function'`. As said, you write JS there, it's not TS type. If you want it to be typed correctly then type it correctly, like `movie: null as Movie | null`

Comment: @EstusFlask Can you be more specific? Thanks!

Comment: `movie: null as Movie | null` should be specified inside `data` instead of `movie: Movie`

Comment: @EstusFlask It does not fix the problem.

Comment: In which way? This is how it's supposed to be done, at least with data. Please, be more specific, otherwise your problem cannot be solved. The most reliable way is to not use options api in Vue 3 because it doesn't work well enough with TS

Comment: can you make sure that the response.data is actually returning data in format as you are expecting ?

Comment: Also better is you declare an interface for your movie type  and then initialize that to as default movie

Comment: could you create a stackblitz?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use classes for typing.

[Classes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes) are templates for creating object instances. To declare their types you should use [interfaces](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html) and/or [types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html).

In short, change this:

```
export class Movie {
    id?: number;
    adult?: boolean;
    backdrop_path?: string;
    poster_path?: string;
    title?: string;
    tagline?: string;
    overview?: string;
    genre_ids?: any;
    original_title?: string;
    release_date?: string;
    runtime?: number;
    vote_average?: string;
}
```

...to this:

```
export interface Movie {
    id?: number;
    adult?: boolean;
    backdrop_path?: string;
    poster_path?: string;
    title?: string;
    tagline?: string;
    overview?: string;
    genre_ids?: any;
    original_title?: string;
    release_date?: string;
    runtime?: number;
    vote_average?: string;
}
```

And you're [good to go](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-typescript-vue-cli-starter-58r77q?file=src%2Fcomponents%2FMovieDetails.vue,src%2Fmodels%2FMovie.ts).

Comment: All is well, except this little thing: when _there is_ a movie poster, before _it_ loads, the generic poster appears (for a fraction of a second, yet visible). Any suggestion? Thanks!

Comment: @RazvanZamfir, you should ask that question separately, so it could help anyone with a similar issue in the future. From what you shared it's unclear what displays the generic poster. Most likely, it's what gets rendered before `getMovieDetails` resolves.